# Slow Network Performance while Sending files ONLY not receiving files

Tags: networking, windows-xp, network-shares, home-networking

I have two windowx xp machine

**Machine A** Map Network Drive **Machine B**

I can **receive** files from Machine B very well  , but it's very slow when **sending** files from Machine A to machine B

The Problem in the Machine B because i changed the Machine A to another Machine and it shows the same problem

I also checked the network cable and still the problem presist

No firewall between the all machines

Note : Mahchine B network share files protected by password
Note : the two machines connected via crossover cable

Comment: When you are sending files to Machine B it is performing writes to it's hard drive. It's possible that the hard drive in Machine B is failing or just slow compared to Machine A. Writes are always slower than reads. Has sending files to Machine B ever been fast?

Comment: there is no write problem with my hard disk , because machine b have two partitions drive , i can read and write , copy and move files very fast

Comment: You may have a problem with the virus scanner on machine b (try do deactivate the background scanner) if this doesn't help, you may have an notify change Problem. Look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330929/en-us/). Try to change the settings under `How to Turn Off Change Notify Requests for All Users` on both machines. Reboot after the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no difference in the disk read/writes, try changing the speed settings on the Network Interface Cards.  Most are set to Auto-negotiate by default but sometimes they don't negotiate well.  Change both NIC's to the same setting (100Mb Full, 100Mb Half, etc.)

Comment: both NIC hard coded to 100MB Full Duplex and i still have the problem . notice that two machines connected to un-sheild twisted peer UTP crossover cable

Comment: Then I'm back to looking at your disk write speed compared to its read speed on Machine B. Two partitions doesn't mean your writes will be faster than reads.  FiZi is correct, "Writes are always slower than reads.", no matter what your configuration is.